# Cannot remove header plus won't find my file

Tags: python-2.7, header, user-defined-functions

I have this main funtion and inside I have the removeHeader one which I have defined as:

```
def removeHeader (file_name):
     f = open(file_name).readlines()
     firstLine = f.pop(6)
     return firstLine
```

main funtion:

```
def readTasksFile(file_name):
    """Reads a file with a list of translation tasks into a collection.  
"""

    inFile = removeHeader(open(file_name, "r"))       

    tasksList = [] 
    for line in inFile:
        taskData = line.rstrip().split(", ")
        tasksList.append(taskData)        

    return tasksList
```

the problem is, it won't find my file plus I'm pretty sure the removeHeader one is missing something, I have looked at some questions about removing lines that have already been asked here but I don't really understand most of them because as a freshman in college right now I'm very bad at programming

Answer (score 0):

In your `removeHeader` method you're trying open a file, but while calling the method `removeHeader` you're already passing the file handler.
Replacing `inFile = removeHeader(open(file_name, "r"))`  with 
`inFile = removeHeader(file_name)` in your `readTasksFile` should work